# How to implement a preloader .gif in PHP, SQL and JSON response situation

Tags: php, json, mysqli, preloader

Can anybody suggest a good way to implement a preloader .gif in the following set up:

On my first page I have a rather long form with several checkboxes. After the user completes the form and clicks submit the values are stored in a database. I then redirect to another file that has a fairly complicated bunch of SQL statements that comparers the users answers against several tables in my database and churns out a list of values that I then put into an array. This array is then then passed into a function containing a few API calls. This whole process can take quite a bit of time as you can imagine so I'd really like to give some feedback to the user in the form of an animated preloader. There's a lot of info online with regards to preloaders but I'm not really sure how or where I should do it.

Just to give some more detail, I have far too much code to try to post here but the exact layout is as follows.

1. HTML form with checkboxes, SQL insert statement. Once the data has been inserted I use header('Location: x.php') to redirect to:
2. ...the file with a series of SQL statements which generates an array with a bunch of values from the database. I send that array of values into:
3. ...a function in another file that calls at least two APIs (Yelp) and prints the results in a loop.

Any help at all would be great - am I even going about this whole process in the best way?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of PHP, you'll need a client-side scripting language (e.g. JavaScript) to monitor loading progress. Anyways, there are too many ways to do so. What have you tried? Show us codes.

Comment: Generally, you would implement progress animation on the client side. With that said, you would need AJAX and JavaScript. PHP usually caches the process results in the buffer and only starts to transmit it when the whole thing is completed. So, you just have to show the preloader.gif once the form is submitted then print result and remove preloader.gif when results are returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have to change anything on the server side (.php files). All you need to do to achieve this is implementing AJAX with JavaScript on the client side ie. HTML/JS.

Below is an example to doing this.

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .hide { display: none; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<div class="loading hide"><svg width='120px' height='120px' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" class="uil-default"><rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="none" class="bk"></rect><rect  x='46.5' y='40' width='7' height='20' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#00b2ff' transform='rotate(0 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46.5' y='40' width='7' height='20' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#00b2ff' transform='rotate(30 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.08333333333333333s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46.5' y='40' width='7' height='20' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#00b2ff' transform='rotate(60 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.16666666666666666s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46.5' y='40' width='7' height='20' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#00b2ff' transform='rotate(90 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.25s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46.5' y='40' width='7' height='20' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#00b2ff' transform='rotate(120 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.3333333333333333s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46.5' y='40' width='7' height='20' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#00b2ff' transform='rotate(150 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.4166666666666667s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46.5' y='40' width='7' height='20' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#00b2ff' transform='rotate(180 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.5s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46.5' y='40' width='7' height='20' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#00b2ff' transform='rotate(210 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.5833333333333334s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46.5' y='40' width='7' height='20' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#00b2ff' transform='rotate(240 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.6666666666666666s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46.5' y='40' width='7' height='20' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#00b2ff' transform='rotate(270 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.75s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46.5' y='40' width='7' height='20' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#00b2ff' transform='rotate(300 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.8333333333333334s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46.5' y='40' width='7' height='20' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#00b2ff' transform='rotate(330 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.9166666666666666s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect></svg></div>
<div id="result"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function($, window, document) {
    $("form").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
        $(".loading").removeClass("hide");
        $.get("submit.php", function(e) {
            $(".loading").addClass("hide");
            $("#result").html(e);
        });
    });
})(jQuery, window, document);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

## PHP

#### submit.php

```
<?php

sleep(5);

header('Location: x.php');
```

#### x.php

```
<?php

sleep(3);

$arr = [];
for ($i=0; $i<1000; $i++) {
    $arr[] = [
        rand()
    ];
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: `sleep()` is not necessary.

Comment: @Raptor Neither was the random number generator. It was there to emphasize the loading animation, simulate some backend process and ultimately visualize what Sio explained.

Comment: @josephting Thanks for your help. Will try to implement your suggestion later this evening. Will keep you posted. Cheers

Comment: Sorry for the delay on this @josephting. Project got completely side tracked and only picking it up again now. Worked perfectly! Thanks